# How to rename the multiply VM hostname in azure\how can I deploy multiple instances of VM from custom image with different hostname

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I want to create 70 VM's of the same OS in Azure. For this, I have created a VM converted to a custom image of it so that I can deploy 70 instances of this machine.

The issue here for me is if I deploy 70 instances of VM via custom images I am getting the hostname of all the VM's as same. All 70 VM's hostname is WIN2K12.

Is there any way where I can change this hostname while deploying?

Comment: What command are you using to create the VM? Are you using CLI?

Comment: You can try to create the VM through Azure template and with a VM extension to change the hostname using a custom shell script.

Comment: PowerShell Script

Comment: How you created your custom image ? Normally, if you follow procedures, sysprep should remove network configuration from image during Generalize phase https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource, and you should have hostname equal to Azure VM name

Comment: I have used a Create custom Image option and selected No on the Sysprep option for the VM. Based on this custom image created I am deploying multiple machines which is of same hostname as of now

Comment: @  Charles Xu - MSFT. I am new to the Azure platform. could please share any link or procedure to do this?

Comment: @sidprasher I am not using CLI. I am trying using GUI custom image option.

Comment: Yeah, take a look at the [Azure template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates). Hope this would help you.

Comment: @san I suggest you to choose sysprep option, it will remove all your custom network settings from image

Answer (score 1):

I'm dealing with the same question right now and my solution is run a remote PowerShell command through Azure CLI (Linux shell in the example below) in the VMs that need to have their hostnames changed. Basically is something like this:

```
$RG       = "Your Resource Group Name"
$OLD_NAME = "The replicated hostname name"
$NEW_NAME = "The new hostname"
$VM_NAME  = "The VM's name that you just created/copied"

     az vm run-command invoke \
                    --resource-group $RG  \
                    --name $VM_NAME \
                    --command-id RunPowerShellScript \
                    --scripts "Rename-Computer -ComputerName $OLD_NAME -NewName $NEW_NAME"
```

I guess you can adapt it to get parameters from command line etc.

Don't forget to restart the VMs after this.

Answer (score 0):

#### Point of clarification.

If you create VM from a Image they will not/should not have the same Hostname. Part of process of making an Azure Custom Image is to **sysprep** machine which guarantees the hostname will be different when you deploy new VM using that image.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource

In Azure the only time VM will get the same host name is if you create VM from a **specialized disk**, meaning create VM from a copy of the same disk (not really image).

The thing you have to confirm is if your applications on the VM allows sysprep.

Comment: I have used a Create custom Image option and selected No on the Sysprep option for the VM. Based on this custom image created I am deploying multiple machines which is of same hostname as of now. Do you suggest to run Sysprep while creating custom image? will that work for me?

Answer (score 0):

Since you chose "NO" on SysPrep the image is not generalized. You're basically creating 70 copies of the same harddrive and starting them. Sysprep ensures that the server upon boot accepts either manual or scripted input to change hostname among other things.